# How to get the current screen after sending a mail from the app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.setType("text/plain");

   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "From my site");

   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, card.text + "\n\n"
     + "Sent from my site " + " "
     + "http://www.mysite.com");
   startActivity(intent);
```

I did this in my application, and after sending the email my application exits, but I don't want it to. After sending the email I want it to return to the screen from my app. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should not exit. In fact I tried out your code on my machine and it came back to the activity fine.

I think your application may be crashing somewhere just after this particular piece of code. Try debugging it, or maybe check your logcat for possible exceptions !